# Sitecore Geo IP : Failed to read GeoIp data for Ip from lookup

Tags: geo-location

We have implemented `Sitecore Geo IP` in the `Sitecore 10.0` version.
The `Geo IP` is working fine in most cases but sometimes for some Users/IP, it will not work and we get the below exception.

```
Falied to read GeoIp data for Ip:'c2e3273a-680c-165d-fa30-ab797b800a98' from lookup
Exception: Polly.CircuitBreaker.BrokenCircuitException
Message: The circuit is now open and is not allowing calls.
Source: Polly
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitStateController`1.OnActionPreExecute()
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()

Nested Exception
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: geoIpServiceUri
Source: Sitecore.CES.GeoIp
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.RequestGeoIpService(String ip)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(String ip)
```

Also, the site is hosted on `Azure Paas`.
Looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed the issue with the help of sitecore support.

Actually we had upgraded our sitecore licence and for the new licence we had not activated the geolocation service. Hence we were not getting the geolocation data.
Once we activated the service, geolocation started working as expected.

For some IPs it was working fine before the fix because the geolocation data was cached for those IPs.